# Matplotlib plotting descending graph with Bitcoin price data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the Bitcoin historical data on a Matplotlib graph using the [this](https://www.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/historical-data) (2010-2024 CSV file) dataset.

When I graph it using Matplotlib, it gives the attached graph.
[image]

I have tried the same exact code with a different dataset (using the [Solana crypto price dataset](https://www.investing.com/crypto/solana/historical-data), it has the same exact CSV keys, just different values), and its graph is attached.
[image]

Here is my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sk
import random
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron

csv = pd.read_csv("./bitcoin-historical-trading-data.csv")
model = Perceptron()

csv['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv['Date'])
csv['Date'] = (csv['Date'].astype('int64') / 10**9).astype('int64') * 1000
csv = csv[["Date", "Price"]]

date = np.array(csv["Date"])
price = np.array(csv["Price"])

mp.plot(date, price)
mp.show()
```

Please let me know if you have any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Did you forget to include the current plots?

Comment: Also, please use the more standard matplotlib import statement: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: @jared Hey, yup sorry, I thought I uploaded the images of the plots and turns out it didn't upload. The question should be updated now. I've also changed the import statement in my local code, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to convert the data to a numpy array to plot it (though you can convert it using `csv["Price"].to_numpy()`). You can pass the Series to Matplotlib (`plt.plot(csv["Date"], csv["Price"])`) or call `plot` directly with Pandas (`df.plot(x="Date", y="Price")`). You can also make the dates `datetime` objects so the x-axis can use the dates rather than the time in whatever units you've converted it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a Matplotlib plot with that many ticks, the first thing you should consider is that your data might not be numerical, see the [Matplotlib FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order).

To verify, print out `csv.dtypes` and I'm guessing the `"Price"` column will be of `object` type. Looking at the links you provided, the Bitcoin data is in the thousands while the Solana is not. Without an account I cannot download the data, but if the saved data has those commas, Pandas will read them as strings (and make them `object`s). Remove those commas and cast the data to a `float`.

```py
csv["Price"] = csv["Price"].str.replace(",", "").astype(float)
```

Comment: Yup, that was exactly the issue. Thanks!

Unfortunately it won't let me upvote your answer because I don't have over 15 reputation, thanks so much for the help!